# How to match against only a subset of dataframe elements using dplyr?

Tags: r, indexing, dplyr, match

In the image shown immediately below, I am trying to replicate the yellow column labeled "Match" using `dplyr`. All columns except for "Match" and "Match description" are accurately generated with the reproducible code below.

Running this match requires some sort of subsetting of the dataframe into rows where `GroupSplit` is not NA (enclosed in heavy borders in the image below) - the values to match are inside these borders. Then, these matched values are imposed in the open cells where `GroupSplit` is NA as illustrated with arrows in the image below.

Also note, as stated at the bottom of the image, when there are duplicate rows for matching (Element Counts 1 and 2 in this example), the lowest of the applicable `GroupSplit` value is to be used; in this example, 1 and 2 have the same `GroupSplit` values but this will not always be the case.

Any recommendations for how to do this?

[image]

Reproducible code:

```
library(dplyr)

myData <- 
  data.frame(
    Element = c("A","B","B","B","B","A","C","C","C","C","C"),
    Group = c(0,1,1,2,2,0,3,3,0,0,0)
  )

excelCopy <- myData %>% 
  group_by(Element) %>% 
  mutate(ElementCnt = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(GroupRank = case_when(Group > 0 ~ match(Group, unique(Group)),TRUE ~ ElementCnt)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Element, Group) %>%
  mutate(SubgroupRank = ifelse(Group == 0, NA, row_number()))%>%
  mutate(GroupSplit = case_when(!is.na(SubgroupRank) ~ as.numeric(paste(GroupRank,SubgroupRank,sep = '.'))))
  
print.data.frame(excelCopy)
```

Comment: Honestly, it is very difficult to see the point of your question through the several crossed lines of your screenshot. For instance, cell F7 has lines that refer the range C7:C12, could you explain how F7 arrives at its value of 2.2 using this range of cells?

Comment: I revised the image to better explain. Cell F7 now refers to cells C7 and C12 and not a range. Note the arrow heads I added to the brackets to indicate 2 specific cells and not a range. This is saying cell C12 (with value 3), outside the index range with the black border, needs to find the same value 3 in the index inside the range with the black border, which is cell C7.  Cell C7 has a GroupSplit value of 2.1 (cell F7), which, following the blue arrow, carries that value of 2.1 down to cell G12, thus providing the match for cell C12. Nevertheless I received correct answers to the question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe this should work

```
library(data.table)
setDT(excelCopy)
#create a rownumber
excelCopy[, rownumber := .I]
# sort by groupSplit, so that the lowest number is always on top
setkey(excelCopy, GroupSplit)
excelCopy[is.na(GroupSplit), 
          match := excelCopy[is.na(GroupSplit), ][excelCopy[!is.na(GroupSplit), ], 
                                         match := i.GroupSplit, 
                                         on = .(ElementCnt)]$match][]
setkey(excelCopy, rownumber)
excelCopy[, rownumber := NULL][]

    Element Group ElementCnt GroupRank SubgroupRank GroupSplit match
 1:       A     0          1         1           NA         NA   1.1
 2:       B     1          1         1            1        1.1    NA
 3:       B     1          2         1            2        1.2    NA
 4:       B     2          3         2            1        2.1    NA
 5:       B     2          4         2            2        2.2    NA
 6:       A     0          2         2           NA         NA   1.2
 7:       C     3          1         1            1        1.1    NA
 8:       C     3          2         1            2        1.2    NA
 9:       C     0          3         3           NA         NA   2.1
10:       C     0          4         4           NA         NA   2.2
11:       C     0          5         5           NA         NA    NA
```

Comment: Wow, beautiful! I just wish I understood data.table better!

Comment: Hi Wimpel, how could this be done in straight dplyr? Your results are accurate but I don't understand data.table very well and the lists to sort/match will never be very long obviating the need for speed offered by data.table. dplyr seems far simpler for the novice like me. One day I'll take the time to learn data.table if I can find a book like "Data.table for Dummies"

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you simply want to merge the rows that have a missing `GroupSplit` with the rows that don't have a missing `GroupSplit`, where the latter set is constrained to have the lowest `GroupSplit` value by `ElementCnt`.

```
# first, remove the grouping structure your your data preparation code
excelCopy <- ungroup(excelCopy)


# second, get the minimum GroupSplit value by ElementCnt, and left_join
# this back to original data

excelCopy %>% 
  group_by(ElementCnt) %>% 
  summarize(Match = min(GroupSplit,na.rm=T)) %>% 
  left_join(excelCopy, by="ElementCnt") %>% 
  mutate(Match=if_else(!is.na(GroupSplit),NA_real_,Match)) %>% 
  relocate(Match, .after=everything()) %>% 
  mutate(Match = if_else(is.infinite(Match),NA_real_,Match))
```

Output:

```
   ElementCnt Element Group GroupRank SubgroupRank GroupSplit Match
        <int> <chr>   <dbl>     <int>        <int>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1          1 A           0         1           NA       NA     1.1
 2          1 B           1         1            1        1.1  NA  
 3          1 C           3         1            1        1.1  NA  
 4          2 B           1         1            2        1.2  NA  
 5          2 A           0         2           NA       NA     1.2
 6          2 C           3         1            2        1.2  NA  
 7          3 B           2         2            1        2.1  NA  
 8          3 C           0         3           NA       NA     2.1
 9          4 B           2         2            2        2.2  NA  
10          4 C           0         4           NA       NA     2.2
11          5 C           0         5           NA       NA    NA
```

Faster and more concise with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(excelCopy)
excelCopy[excelCopy[, .(Match = min(GroupSplit, na.rm=T)), ElementCnt],
          on="ElementCnt"][!is.na(GroupSplit), Match:=NA ][]
```

Output:

```
    Element Group ElementCnt GroupRank SubgroupRank GroupSplit Match
     <char> <num>      <int>     <int>        <int>      <num> <num>
 1:       A     0          1         1           NA         NA   1.1
 2:       B     1          1         1            1        1.1    NA
 3:       C     3          1         1            1        1.1    NA
 4:       B     1          2         1            2        1.2    NA
 5:       A     0          2         2           NA         NA   1.2
 6:       C     3          2         1            2        1.2    NA
 7:       B     2          3         2            1        2.1    NA
 8:       C     0          3         3           NA         NA   2.1
 9:       B     2          4         2            2        2.2    NA
10:       C     0          4         4           NA         NA   2.2
11:       C     0          5         5           NA         NA    NA
```